# Ordering a child nav in a two tiered Navigation

Tags: wordpress

I made a two tiered Navigation in Wordpress custom theme. It is working great, but does anyone know if it possible to manually change it's order?

Here is the code from my custom header:

```
<div id="secNav">

<?php if($post->post_parent)  

$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); else  
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");  

if ($children && is_page()) { ?>  
<ul id="subnav"> 
<span class="subDescript"><?php echo $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); ?>         Section:</span>   
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>  
<?php } else { ?>  
<?php } ?>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort_column` parameter of `wp_list_pages`

```
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
```

Setting it to `menu_order` will allow you to use custom sorting by specifying a sort order in your page editor (under Page Attributes)

Comment: Thank you, I added 'sort_column=menu_order' to my code and it worked! I really appreciate it... big time.

Comment: Great. Please show your appreciation by accepting and/or up voting my answer.